# How to run express's scaffold using "nodemon" and simple "node" command, without using "npm start" command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I think i have to change my package.json file but i don't know where?
here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.13.3",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.4.5",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an entry for main and as follows and do `nodemon`

```
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "main": "./bin/www",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.13.3",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.4.5",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Then do

`nodemon`

This should now work exactly as `npm start`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Let me try this. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Dave Amit, I got my answer. now i can run my code with nodemon and using with "node ./bin/www".

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark it as answer as other can find this easily.